# Create a random hash from Nginx and happen to query string

Tags: url, hash, nginx

in short I'd like nginx to generate a random hash when any given url is accessed and happen that unique hash to the query string.

So that, when accessing http://www.mysite.com/
the Url be rewritten as: http://www.mysite.com/AjiJfaGVCJzwBMEoqYd3r929fz1l2fiuh

Thank you

Comment: Don't think nginx provides that. Have you tried this 3rd party module? https://github.com/simpl/ngx_http_set_hash

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use nginx built-in perl module: [ngx_http_perl_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_perl_module.html).

Perl-based request handler can generate random and/or any desirable hash string and then redirect user to the new link.

Comment: Marked as answered with the caveat I didn't try it - ended up manipulating headers in node.js instead.